# Могут ли Dictionary Keys быть одинаковыми?

Tags: c#, unity3d, словари

*Есть Dictionary:*

```
Dictionary < Key, Val> foo;
```

В него добавляются элементы с уникальными ключами. Понятно, что если есть ключи, то они и должны быть уникальными.

*Проблема:*

Существуют ситуации, когда объекты-ключи `Dictionary` уничтожаются. Тогда получается, что `Dictionary` будет иметь ключи, которые `null`.

*Вопрос:*

Как удалить эти ключи и можно ли их удалять обычным способом?

Comment: Каким образом ключи уничтожаются? Как это сделает их равными `null`, если `Dictionary` хранит свою собственную копию ссылки на ключ?

Comment: Я работаю в Unity. В документации сказано, что если вызвать DestroyImmediate, то вызовется сборщик мусора, кторый 1)удалит обьект 2) Занулит все ссылки на него. Думаете в Dictionary он ничего не занулит?

Comment: 1. Советую перед уничтожением объекта-ключа удалить его из списка.

Comment: 2. не рекомендую использовать объект как ключ, это не безопасно и не выгодно, в плане производительности. Можно использовать обычный `int` ключ, пример `foo.Add(someObject.GetInstanceID(), someObject)`.

Answer (score 4):

`Dictionary<TKey, Tvalue>` содержит элементы `KeyValuePair(TKey, TValue)`. Ключи должны быть уникальными. При удалении элемента - удаляется пара целиком, т.е. никаких `null`-значений в ключах быть не может. Если существует хотя бы одна активная достижимая ссылка на объект - объект не будет удален из памяти.

Отдельный случай, когда объект реализует `IDisposable` и был вызван метод `Dispose()`. Но тут есть два важных момента: 1. Использовать такие объекты в качестве ключей не самая хорошая идея; 2. Вызов `Dispose()`, как правило, выполняет освобождению критичных и/или неуправляемых ресурсов и не влияет на доступность самого объекта. Таким образом может существовать объект на котором применили `Dispose()`, но он при этом не собран сборщиком мусора, так как на него есть ссылки. Пользы от такого объекта чуть меньше чем ни какой, но он вполне может висеть в словаре в качестве ключа. Таким образом и тут описанной вами проблемы не наблюдается.

Comment: Выходит, если правильно вас понял, если удалить обьект, то он сам полностью удалится в Dictionary? Я не совсем понимаю как в C# это произойдет.   ___ По идее счетчик ссылок должен быть равен 0. Но Dictionary хранит в себе ссылку на обьект и это уже +1 ссылка, что не позволит сборщику мусора удалять ключ. Тогда вообще возможно ли что обькт удалится даже если в документации Unity написано, что удалится?

Comment: @Alerr Где метка `Unity` под вопросом? Но это формальность. Удалить ключ без значения из словаря нельзя, либо всю пару, либо только значение. Ключ со значением `null` может быть по идее, но только в единственном числе, попытка добавить еще один такой ключ закончится исключением. И нет, само из словаря ни чего не удалится, сами положили - сами удаляйте.

Comment: @rdorn да по идее в принципе не может быть `null`-ключа

Comment: @yolosora проверил - действительно не может быть. Там завязка на `GetHashCode()`, а его из `null` не дернешь, это я с БД попутал, там то `NULL` может быть при ограничении `UNIQUE` =)

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант...

Использоуйте LINQ для определения ключей, value которых = null:

```
var keys = dictionary.Where(x => x.Value == null).Select(s => s.Key);
```

Ну и дальше пройтись циклом и удалить из словаря:

```
foreach (var key in keys)
{
    dictionary.Remove(key);
}
```

Можно объединить и сделать один LINQ запрос на удаление подобных ключей:

```
dictionary.Where(x => x.Value == null)
          .Select(s => s.Key).ToList()
          .ForEach(d => dictionary.Remove(d));
```

Ну а вообще, это желательно делать при удаление value из словаря, а не "когда то, в далекие времена..".

Answer (score 0):

Реализуйте классу объекта-ключа публичный метод Remove().
В этом методе класс будет удалять себя из словаря, в котором он записан, а потом уничтожать свой объект. Когда объект-ключ нужно удалить - вызывайте этот метод.

Решение с поиском null ключей может не помочь, в связи с особенностями реализации сравнения в Unity. Там у них своя обёртка на c# объектом. В итоге, объекта может уже не быть, а обёртка ещё жива и при сравнении с null - будет выдавать false, а при попытке вызвать метод - будет падать ошибка.